# Can I create a Qt Creator project with custom boilerplate template?

Tags: c++, qt-creator

Is there any to change the default boilerplate code in the .cpp file when creating a new project in Qt Creator?

Currently, new C++ projects open with:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I would like to change it.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I edited my question

Comment: It would be great to indicate what is the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained here https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html and for C++ projects you'll find the default `main.cpp` boilerplate code in `qtcreator/templates/wizards/projects/plaincpp`.

So basically you need to define a new custom wizard.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer or give a vote up if you think it is correct. In this way, other people can refer to it in the future if they have the same question.

Comment: Thanks Scab. I can’t upvote yet, but I just accepted it.